# GWT 2.5 plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

we have an old project which runs on the GWT 2.5. Can anyone help me to install the GWT plugin for 2.5 version. I am using Eclipse Kepler and Indigo.
I have tried to install the plugin available in GWT portal. it will install 2.6. and it need a Java version of 7. I need a GWT plugin for version 2.5 which contains appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5 & gwt-2.5.0

Thanks,
Akshay

Comment: How to configure in eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a different plugin, you just need a local GWT 2.5 SDK. You can configure your GWT SDK in the Eclipse preferences under "Google > Web Toolkit".

You can download old GWT SDKs on [the GoogleCode project](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list)

Edit: You need to extract the manually downloaded GWT SDK before you can configure it in Eclipse.

Edit2: Old Appengine SDKs can be [downloaded on Google Developers](https://console.developers.google.com/storage/appengine-sdks/deprecated/). The Appengine SDK can be configured in Eclipse preferences under "Google > App Engine".

Comment: How to configure in eclipse ?

Comment: 1. download and unpack a GWT SDK as described above
2. Go to the Eclipse preferences dialog (this depends on your OS) then select "Google > Web Toolkit"
3. Add the SDK you unpacked in step 1. and make it the default
4. press ok

Comment: In preferences "Google" is not available. How to get that.

Comment: It's part of the Google Plugin for eclipse (GPE) -> http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/google-plugin-eclipse-43

Comment: I did the same way as u told but still facing the same issue. "App Engine requires Java 1.7 or later."

Comment: Old App Engine SDKs can be downloaded here: https://console.developers.google.com/storage/appengine-sdks/deprecated/